# Payara Admin must be enabled to access the DAS remotely

Tags: linux, debian, payara

I was facing the following error on Payara41's Admin Console:
[image]

So I tried to enable admin security with the following:

```
$ ./asadmin --host localhost enable-admin-security --port 4949
```

But I get:

```
Unknown error
Command enable-admin-security failed.
```

I've also tried without `--host` and `--port` options, but then:

```
Command enable-admin-security not found. 
Check the entry of command name. This command may be provided by a 
package that is not installed.
Command enable-admin-security failed.
```

Has anyone already faced this kind of problem with Payara 4.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable secure admin, use `enable-secure-admin` command instead of `enable-admin-security` as following;

```
$ ./asadmin --host localhost enable-secure-admin --port 4949
```

If you have not set admin password yet (in the default, admin password is not set), you need to set using 'change-admin-password' command before run 'enable-secure-admin'.

Comment: You are right. 
I don't know where the hell I figured out 'enable-admin-security". Thank you.